# Perodically Checking for Connectivity in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I read through the documentation from Firebase on checking connectivity, but not clear it matches my use case. We have an IoT device we created that were using to send to data to Firebase and then out to the users phone. We plan to connect the device to local network and then would send data to Firebase. We don't plan to keep the connection open but would send data every 15 minutes. If we can't send the data we will store it on the device until it can get a new connection.

Out of the methods that Firebase has, what is the best way to track/alert on a dropped connection to Firebase? Hope that made sense...

Thanks!

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

Answer (score 0):

A presence system is simply a way of sharing your status with other users. At a basic level, this status could be something simple like whether a given user is currently online or offline. Firebase is great at doing exactly that - sharing state.
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html?m=1

Comment: Rather than linking to external URL, please add relevant code and explanation in the answer.